# How do you add 2 jquery events in a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 jquery events that call asynchronously in a script tag.

However only the first one works...

**Code:**

```
<script>
    $('#type').bind('change', function (e) 
        {
            $.getJSON('<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/this/url/go/' + encodeURIComponent($('#type').val()),
            function(data) 
            {
                $("#more").html(data.form);
            }
            );
    });

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response)
          {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'this/new/url/' + request.term,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    response(data);
                }  
            })
          },
          minLength:2
        });
</script>
```

Only the first function works, i've also tested it where just the bottom script is there and it worked.

What noob error am I making?

**HTML:**

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
<dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="type-label"><label for="type" class="optional">Select a Type:</label>
</dt>
<dd id="type-element">
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="various" label="options etc">Annual Report</option>
</select></dd></dl></form>
<div id='more'>
</div>
```

then this is added with ajax:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post"><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="search-label"><label for="search" class="optional">Search Code:</label></dt>
<dd id="search-element">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value=""></dd></dl></form>
```

Comment: show HTML also. Is `search` and `type` available when the page loads first time or they loaded using ajax?

Comment: search is loaded using ajax murali

Comment: Then move `$( "#search" ).autocomplete({` function inside ajax success call back after you set the .html(data)

Answer (score 1):

This works properly with both `bind` and `autocomplete`, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QCCr/)

When you load the `search` element sometime later, you must move the

```
$("#search").autocomplete(...);
```

call behind the code, where you create or load the search element.

Answer (score 0):

write your code in [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) like below

add jquery file first

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // your code
      $('#type').bind('change', function (e) 
            {
                $.getJSON('<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/this/url/go/' + encodeURIComponent($('#type').val()),
                function(data) 
                {
                    $("#more").html(data.form);
                }
                );
        });

        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
              source: function(request, response)
              {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'this/new/url/' + request.term,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        response(data);
                    }  
                })
              },
              minLength:2
            });

    })
</script>
```

Comment: sorry @rituraj, i did not mention that the `search` DOM element is loaded with ajax so it isn't there when the page initially loads

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap your methods using On (if u r using Jquery 1.8 or more) or live (below jQuery 1.7)method

```
<script>
   $(body).on('change','#type',function(e){
    ('<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/this/url/go/' + encodeURIComponent($('#type').val()),
                function(data) 
                {
                    $("#more").html(data.form);
                }
                );
        });
    $(body).on('focus','#search',function(e)
{
        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
              source: function(request, response)
              {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'this/new/url/' + request.term,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        response(data);
                    }  
                })
              },
              minLength:2
            });
});
<script/>
```

Comment: `live` is bad even below 1.7. Use `delegate` if you can't upgrade. Even rolling your own delegation is better than `live`.